# How to remove navigationbar image shadow for ios 14?

Tags: objective-c, shadow, navigationbar, ios14

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Y1W.jpg)
I am Facing **ios version** issue in objective c. **Navigationbar image shadow** is not working in **ios 14 version**. and ios **< 14** working fine. i upload image
so here is my code

---

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 14.0)
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: [UIImage new]
                                       forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [UINavigationBar appearance].shadowImage = [UIImage new];

    //[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:blank forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
else
{
    // Load resources for iOS 11 or earlier
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage alloc];

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In objective - c

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: [UIImage new]
                                   forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = UIColor.clearColor;
```

In Swift 5

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarPosition: UIBarPosition.Any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = false
```

Comment: Where did you find the possibility to call setBackgroundImage and shadowImage on UINavigationBar.appearance() ?

Comment: I already worked on it.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved issue below is my code:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 14.0)
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: [UIImage new]
                                       forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    [UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = UIColor.clearColor;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

}
else
{
    // Load resources for iOS 11 or earlier
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage alloc];

}
```

Comment: yes and is it work for ios 15? that's work for 14 that's good.